# Unable to install the driver for "AVerTV Volar HD Nano - A867R" (a DVB-T dongle)

Tags: usb, software-installation, driver, television-tuner

I downloaded the driver (for linux) from the [AVerMedia site](http://avermedia.com/tv_more/download/avertv_volar_hd_nano#ans_part), unpacked it into an xyz directory, and from that directory I gave the command
`make`.
I got the following output

```
Missing files that required to build driver: /lib/modules/4.9.35-v7+/source/drivers/media/dvb/dvb-usb/dvb-usb-common.h dvb-usb/dvb-usb.h dvb-usb/dvb-usb-ids.h dvb-core/dvb_frontend.h dvb-core/dvbdev.h dvb-core/dmxdev.h dvb-core/dvb_demux.h dvb-core/dvb_net.h dvb-core/demux.h dvb-core/dvb_ringbuffer.h frontends/dvb-pll.h
Try to get kernel source closest to 4.9.35-v7+ from www.kernel.org and then copy to /lib/modules/4.9.35-v7+/source/drivers/media/dvb.
```

Indeed the directory `/lib/modules/4.9.35-v7+` exists on my raspbian installation (raspberry Pi 2) but with no `source` subdirectory under it.

I do not know how to interpret the suggestion above `Try to get kernel source *closest* to 4.9.35-v7+ ...`, and I haven't the slightest idea how I could find and download the required files from that site.

Perhaps it is useless to say, but the command `uname -r`  returns `4.9.35-v7+`

Can anybody please give me instructions (detailed if possible) how-to ...?
*Added later* : Or at least some clarification?

Comment: First install "sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev" and then "sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)".

Comment: "sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev" returned "...dpkg-dev is already the newest version. dpkg-dev set to manually installed...".  "sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)" returned "...E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list...". But which URI I should put? I have no idea...

Comment: in "/etc/apt/sources.list" you should have a row that begins with "deb-src", example "deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi".

Comment: Uncommented the line and issued again `sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)`.  Result was `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for linux-image-4.9.35-v7+`

Comment: Edit of prev. comment timed out. New text is:Uncommented the line and issued `sudo apt-get update` (resulted in a list with many URIs inside - do not know if and how i am supposed to use) and then issued again `sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)`.  (result was `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for linux-image-4.9.35-v7+`)